# Question about the logic of the successor function

Tags: logic

Many similar questions were asked here before, but I can't find an answer that addresses my problem directly. The axiom that introduces the successor function is usually written like so:

$$\forall x \in N: S(x) \in N$$

Now, I know a few things about predicate calculus, but my knowledge stops there (in particular, I know next to nothing about second order logic). What confuses me is that the expression $S(x)$ is used as if it denotes an individual directly (just as $0$ does). But shouldn't it be understood as a 2-place predicate "Sxy", which translates to "y is the successor of x"?

My confusion arose in my attempt to formalize the Peano axioms as given in Tao's Analysis I. I'm precisely interested in such foundational issues, so I'd be happy for clarification. I came up with this:

$$\forall n(n \in N \implies \exists m(S(nm) \land m \in N))$$

Comment: $S(x)$ is not a predicate, but a function. Peano's axioms are in the following language (First-Order Predicate Logic)+a successor function $S$. The function $S: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is unique, predicates and relations are not necessarily unique, which is encapsulated by the following axiom: $\forall(x,y)(S(x)=S(y)\iff x=y)$

Comment: Thank you! And the notion of "function" comes from set theory...?

Comment: I think it would also help me a lot if you could provide some explanation of why predicates needn't be (can't be?) unique. Most probably I'm misunderstanding what "unique" means in this context. Could you give an example of a predicate that is not unique?

Another way to phrase my question: What exactly does my attempt to formalize the axiom leave out? How does it stir up trouble?

Comment: You are welcome, as for where the notion of function came from that's kind of like asking what came first: the chicken or the egg. It depends on where you start from.

Comment: Take, for example, the predicate "is even" Let's call it $E(x)$, we know that $2$ is even. So, $E(2)$. Likewise, we know that $E(4)$ but $2\neq 4$. A function, on the other hand, doesn't tell you anything about an element, all it does is that it maps one element to another, but if you notice with "is even" example a predicate tells you something about an element.

Comment: Translating back and forth between a function and a relation in exactly the way you've done (translating $y=f(x)$ to $R(x,y)$) is a very common tool in branches of mathematics such as model theory. Relations are slightly easier to do model theory with, but functions tend to be more intuitive. We swap freely between these perspectives for convenience.

Comment: Maybe you can help me get a knot out of my brain. S(x) is a function that takes a natural number as its argument and spits out another natural number. But isn't any relation R(x,y) also a function that takes a tuple as its argument and spits out a truth value? 
So, I guess I'm trying to get at the sense in which a relation "tells you something about an element", while a function does not do so. Given that relations *are* functions (if I'm even right about that!), I fail to understand how they could differ in such a sense.

Comment: we *can* view relations as functions that spit out truth values (as opposed to functions which spit out elements of our structure). However when we say R(x,y) we mean "R(x,y) is true" (just as 0<1 means "0<1 is true")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The axiom that introduces the successor function is usually written
> like so: $\forall x \in N: S(x) \in N$

To clarify, it could also be written as: $$\forall x: [x\in N \implies \exists y: [ y\in N ~\land~ y=S(x)]$$

Or more succinctly as:

$$\forall x\in N:\exists y\in N: y=S(x)$$

Or...

$$S:N\to N$$

From your text:

> "Definition 3.3.1 (Functions). Let X, Y be sets, and let P(x, y) be a
> property pertaining to an object x ∈ X and an object y ∈ Y , such that
> for every x ∈ X, there is exactly one y ∈ Y for which P(x, y) is true
> (this is sometimes known as the vertical line test). Then we define
> the function f : X → Y defined by P on the domain X and range Y to be
> the object which, given any input x ∈ X, assigns an output f(x) ∈ Y,
> defined to be the unique object f(x) for which P(x, f(x)) is true.
> Thus, for any x ∈ X and y ∈ Y, y = f(x) ⇐⇒ P(x, y) is true."
>
> --Terence Tao, "Analysis I," p. 49

Comment: Thanks! Your comment and the others have really helped. What would happen if I used the following formalization:

$$\forall n(n \in N \implies \exists! m(S(nm) \land m \in N))$$

Given that I make explicit that it's exactly one m that makes Snm true for all n, is this now equivalent to speaking of a successor function rather than a relation?

Comment: @ichbinviele That would work, but it would be much more cumbersome to use, e.g. in making substitutions or proving the existence of other functions.

Answer (score 1):

s(x) denotes an individual since it’s a function as opposed to a unary predicate. That is, it picks out one and only one object in the universe of discourse. You could define a binary successor relation S(x,y), but you’d have to define it so that ‘x’ is unique.

Comment: Whoever is automatically giving me a downvote every time I comment, please stop.

Comment: Two issues with this answer, the first part is not answer worthy much more suited to be a comment. The second part is flat out wrong.

Comment: How is the second part wrong? And if I can’t answer a question in the “answers” section, why does this site even exist?

Comment: I down-voted the answer because the second part is wrong, not because you answered the question. Two-place predicates are ordered pairs, not unary elements.

Comment: If you’d read the OP and my answer carefully, you’d have pieced together that my mentioning that s(x) is a function as opposed to a unary predicate was to help clear up that the successor function isn’t merely a predicate, which is one of the things that OP was confused about. If you’d read my answer even half as carefully as all that, you’d know that my mention of a two-place predicate was only for the sake of showing that it is possible to get at the same idea as the successor function using a two-place relation, but that provisos would need to be made for the sake of uniqueness.

Comment: I found your (Pdubya) answer helpful, so thank you! (: Sadly, as a new user I can't upvote.